# Remove route mappings in NodeJS Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have a route mapped as:

```
app.get('/health/*', function(req, res){
    res.send('1');
});
```

How can I remove / remap this route to an empty handler at runtime?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This removes `app.use` middlewares and/or `app.VERB` (get/post) routes. Tested on express@4.9.5

```
var routes = app._router.stack;
routes.forEach(removeMiddlewares);
function removeMiddlewares(route, i, routes) {
    switch (route.handle.name) {
        case 'yourMiddlewareFunctionName':
        case 'yourRouteFunctionName':
            routes.splice(i, 1);
    }
    if (route.route)
        route.route.stack.forEach(removeMiddlewares);
}
```

Note that it **requires** that the middleware/route functions have **names**:

```
app.use(function yourMiddlewareFunctionName(req, res, next) {
    ...          ^ named function
});
```

It **won't work** if the function is anonymous:

```
app.get('/path', function(req, res, next) {
    ...          ^ anonymous function, won't work                    
});
```

Comment: In the above, `route.path` contains the path name - if you want to remove an anonymous route by path, you can switch on that instead.

Comment: `route.path` is undefined in my case but `route.route.path` has the correct value

Answer (score 26):

Express (at least as of 3.0.5) keeps all of its routes in `app.routes`.  From the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app-settings):

> The app.routes object houses all of the routes defined mapped by the associated HTTP verb. This object may be used for introspection capabilities, for example Express uses this internally not only for routing but to provide default OPTIONS behaviour unless app.options() is used. Your application or framework may also remove routes by simply by removing them from this object.

Your `app.routes` should look similar to this:

```
{ get: 
   [ { path: '/health/*',
       method: 'get',
       callbacks: [Object],
       keys: []}]
}
```

So, you should be able to loop through `app.routes.get` until you find what you are looking for, and then delete it.

Comment: This is super helpful. However, when I keep trying it I keep running into really strange issues. Is there any way at all you could write out a simple example?

Comment: Particularly, it's deleting all of my static resource mapping too -- do you know why this is? Here's my question for it that has more detail... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487084/removing-a-specfic-mapped-route-in-node-js-at-runtime-removes-static-mapping

Comment: Not anymore, as of express@4.9.5. [Checkout my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378690/remove-route-mappings-in-nodejs-express/28369539#28369539)

Answer (score 9):

The above approach requires you have a named function for the route.  I wanted to do this as well but didn't have named functions for routes so I wrote an npm module that can remove routes by specifying the routing path.

Here you go:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-remove-route

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to remove mounted handlers (added with app.use) while the server is running, although there is no API to do this, so it isn't recommended.

```js
/* Monkey patch express to support removal of routes */
require('express').HTTPServer.prototype.unmount = function (route) {
    for (var i = 0, len = this.stack.length; i < len; ++i) {
        if (this.stack[i].route == route) {
            this.stack.splice(i, 1);
            return true;
        };
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is something I need, so it's a shame there isn't a proper api, but express is just mimicing what connect does here.

Answer (score 4):

```
app.get$ = function(route, callback){
  var k, new_map;

  // delete unwanted routes
  for (k in app._router.map.get) {
    if (app._router.map.get[k].path + "" === route + "") {
      delete app._router.map.get[k];
    }
  }

  // remove undefined elements
  new_map = [];
  for (k in app._router.map.get) {
    if (typeof app._router.map.get[k] !== 'undefined') {
      new_map.push(app._router.map.get[k]);
    }
  }
  app._router.map.get = new_map;

  // register route
  app.get(route, callback);
};

app.get$(/awesome/, fn1);
app.get$(/awesome/, fn2);
```

And then when you go to `http://...awesome` `fn2` will be called :)

Edit: fixed the code

Edit2: fixed again...

Edit3: Maybe simpler solution is to purge routes at some point and repopulate them:

```
// remove routes
delete app._router.map.get;
app._router.map.get = [];

// repopulate
app.get(/path/, function(req,res)
{
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can look into Express [route middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#route-middleware) and possibly do a redirect.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to modify existing routes at all once they're established.  This includes adding new middleware.  Although for now I'm going to use the next('route') command

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned above, the new Express API doesn't seem to support this.

1. Is it really necessary to completely remove the mapping? If all you need is to stop serving a route, you can easily just start returning some error from the handler.

   The only (very odd) case where this wouldn't be good enough is if dynamic routes were added all the time, and you wanted to completely get rid of old ones to avoid accumulating too many...
2. If you want to remap it (either to do something else, or to map it to something that always returns an error), you can always add another level of indirection:

   ```
   var healthHandler = function(req, res, next) {
       // do something
   };

   app.get('/health/*', function(req, res, next) {
       healthHandler(req, res, next);
   });

   // later somewhere:

   healthHandler = function(req, res, next) {
       // do something else
   };
   ```

   In my opinion this is nicer/safer than manipulating some undocumented internals in Express.

Comment: My use case was allowing users to configure routes in a CMS (browser based front end app).  I additionally want to scope those routes based on header information like the `Host` field.  I'm probably going to just route all requests to the same handler and then do my own custom routing outside of the Express routing API.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official method but you can do this with **stack**.

```
function DeleteUserRouter(appName){

router.stack = router.stack.filter((route)=>{
  if(route.route.path == `/${appName}`){
     return false;
  }
  return true;
});
}
```

appName is path name .

Filter the methods in the router.route.stack where the router is express.Router
or you can do the same for the app but with app._router.stack.

**Note**: For below 4.0 use - app.router.stack.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove **all** routes you can iterate backwards over `app._routes.stack` (**1**) or `express.Router().stack` (**2**) and remove each route:

**1. with express app**

```js
let i = app._router.stack.length
while(i--) {
    app._router.stack.splice(i, 1)
}
```

**2. with express.Router()**

```js
let i = router.stack.length
while(i--) {
    router.stack.splice(i, 1)
}
```

#### Working examples

`npm install express`

then

**1. with express app**

```js
const express = require("express")

let app = express()

// Respond on first attempt, then remove all routes
app.get('/health/*', function(req, res){
    res.send('1')
    removeRoutes()
})

function removeRoutes() {
    let i = app._router.stack.length
    while(i--) {
        app._router.stack.splice(i, 1)
    }
}

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app is listening on port 3000.'))
```

**2. with express.Router()**

```js
const express = require("express")

let app = express()

let router = express.Router()

// Respond on first attempt, then remove all routes
router.get('/health/*', function(req, res){
    res.send('1')
    removeRoutes()
})

function removeRoutes() {
    let i = router.stack.length
    while(i--) {
        router.stack.splice(i, 1)
    }
}

app.use('/', router)
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app is listening on port 3000.'))
```