# does expressjs cache the routes? If so how to remove them in development

Tags: node.js, express, requirejs

If there is a change in a module I am deleting the module using require.cache and requiring the module again. it works...but in case of routes in expressjs it would not overwrite the existing routes..new routes are added..infact it would not even delete the deleted routes(i n that module)..how to uncache a module from expressjs as well.or can I request expressjs to overwrite the cache.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove route mappings in NodeJS Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378690/remove-route-mappings-in-nodejs-express)

Comment: I am looking for a way to overwrite the route(get/post routes) with the new callback that came from module load...as it would be complex to know what all routes are being added(to delete them) in each module reload