# How do I remove a GET/POST router endpoint from express?

Tags: node.js, express

So I have defined an express endpoint like:

```
router.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
    res.send('hello');
});
```

Later on in the code, I have something like:

```
router.get('/gosilent', function(req, res) {
    // When this is called, it removes /hello endpoint 
    // such that any subsequent calls to /hello will return standard 404.
});
```

How do I make it work? I know how to bind endpoints but how do I unbind then?

I'm using Express 4.0.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove route mappings in NodeJS Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378690/remove-route-mappings-in-nodejs-express)

Comment: I wanted to know which of those answers is for Express 4. I could not comment on any of the answers and hence I opened up a new question.

Comment: Why not set a variable when the /gosilent route gets hit and check the status of that variable everytime something hits the /hello route before doing the res.send?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought about that but I want to be able to dynamically attach functions in/out of a router endpoint. I can attach them in but can't detach them.