# Returning 401 error for all routes with hapijs

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

We're using *Hapi JS* for our rest server. We store the authentication tokens for the users on Redis. Now, if for some reason *node* loses connection with Redis, we need to return `401 Authorization failed` error to all the clients from all the routes so the clients can logout automatically.

*So, is there a way to return 401 from all routes without changing the code in the route handler functions?*

Comment: Can you [remove all the route mappings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378690/remove-route-mappings-in-nodejs-express/28369539#28369539) and insert a new one?

Comment: Sorry, can't exactly understand the benefit of removing all the mappings. I suppose I need a middleware to achieve this. At least I need the middleware equivalent of a mechanism in hapijs.

Comment: How do you do the Authentication so far?
If you use the hapi Auth mechanism this should happen anyway...

Comment: In any case you could use the onPreResponse hook. I'm not saying you should...but you could ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the Hapi [server extension event](http://hapijs.com/api#serverextevent-method-options) `'onRequest'`.

```
var hapi = require('hapi');
var Boom = require('boom');

var server = new hapi.Server();
//Configure your server

//Add an extension point

server.ext('onRequest', function (request, reply) {
    var status;
    //Check status of redis instance

    if (status) {
        //Redis is running, continue to handler
        return reply.continue();
    } else {
        //Redis is down, reply with error
        return reply(Boom.unauthorized('Auth server is down'));
    }
});
```

This is probably not how you will verify the status your redis instance, but I hope you get the point.

One can look up various other extension points [here](http://hapijs.com/api#request-lifecycle).

Comment: Yes, that's what I did exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in the auth plugin used by your app. Take a look at the hapi-auth-basic implementation: https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-basic/blob/master/lib/index.js

If you look in the scheme you must define an authenticate method which takes the request and reply. This is where you should check redis for an auth token. If the connection is not available you should

`return reply(Boom.unauthorized('Authorization failed', 'Basic'));`

Hope this helps.