# Change Express route path on the fly

Tags: node.js, express

I want to know a way to change a route path on the fly (with the application already running).

```
var route = express.Route();
route.get('a/path/:id', callback);
```

I wan't to change the route with path `'a/path/:id'` to `'another/path/:id'`

Comment: Routes are stored in `app._router.stack` by their function name (like 'callback' in your example, they must not be anonymous!). [Checkout this answer on how to configure them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378690/remove-route-mappings-in-nodejs-express/28369539#28369539), Basically loop through them and find/replace

Comment: I was aware of the stack, but I thought that there's a better way to do this. Thanks.