# Dynamically remove path

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a way to dynamically remove a path from express so that the endpoint will return 404. For example:

```
app.get('./test', handle);
```

Later I would like to do something like:

```
app.get('./test').remove();
```

Comment: What's the use case for this? It'd help to be able to understand exactly what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to create a dynamic simulator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove route mappings in NodeJS Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378690/remove-route-mappings-in-nodejs-express)

Answer (score 3):

I would put a test in your handler rather than removing the path, something like this:

```
var handle = function(req, res) {
    if (yourCondition) {
        res.status(404);
        res.send('This path has been removed');
    }
}
```

Comment: yep this one sounds interesting, dynamically modifying handler is an option.