# node.js express.js API to remove http post handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, http, express

this is my simplified problem, where i attach the http post handler to express, and later I need to remove this attached http post handler

```
var express = require("express")();
...
express.post('/api', function(req,res){..})
... 
//later i need to detach the handler
express.removeListener('/api')
```

after this, there should be no http post handler on /api url, and should be "re-reouted" to default handler, is there any express.js API call i can use?

edit :

can i do something like this as a workaround

`express.post('/api',function(req,res){ res.status(404).send('Not found'); }`

Answer (score 0):

Express has no *official* way of removing routes like that. What you could do is check some flag inside the handler that merely calls `next()` if it the flag is set. You can remove routes by digging into the internals of Express as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378690/remove-route-mappings-in-nodejs-express) however. However when relying on internal/private/undocumented properties like that you should expect potential breakage in the future.

Comment: what happen if i re-bind http post handler with callback that send 404, will it work?