# Remove self route mapping in express js on runtime

Tags: node.js, express

What I am trying to do is, everytime `/some_abc` is being called, with some `POST data uid` new route is mapped with new name `/XYZuid_P`. This is my code

```
var app = require('express')
app.post('/some_abc', function (req, res) {
    app.post('/' +req.body.uid+ '_P', function (reqa, resa) {
        console.log("URL: %s",reqa.url);
        //here TODO
        resa.end();
    });
  res.end();
});
```

I am able to map new route with this piece of code.
Now I want to remove this `/XYZuid_P` route, whenever `/XYZuid_P` is called.

I tried to take help from [Remove route mappings in NodeJS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378690/remove-route-mappings-in-nodejs-express), but unable to remove the route. It is giving `TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined`.

If I am printing `console.log(app._router);` I can see new added route in the list.

Please help how, can I delete route from by itself.

Comment: If I'm getting you correctly, then you are trying to create a temporary route?

Comment: yes, and delete it afterwards

Comment: Check my answer. Only thing is that I haven't tested it.

Comment: for my project, i required this type of thing, to have a temporary post api, which should be deleted afterwards on call! just i was finding how to delete it on run time!

Comment: i already tested, all solutions given to remove the routes, nothing worked, though i got the solution, posted below !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the easy solution for it, sharing it

```
var app = require('express')
app.post('/some_abc', function (req, res) {
    app.post('/' +req.body.uid+ '_P', function (reqa, resa) {
        //This code is removing self route when called next time
        var i=6; // before 6th index route don't exists
        while(app._router.stack[i]){
            if(app._router.stack[i++].route.path == req.url)
                    break;
        }
                                       // i is giving the index location
        app._router.stack.splice(i,1); // this line is responsible for deleting
        resa.end();
    });
  res.end();
});
```

All mapped routes are saved in `app._router.stack`, just by editing this object we can modify routes on run time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution to the problem:

1. Maintain a temporary routes table:

```
    var tempRoutes = {};
```

2. Creating new temporary route:

```
    app.post('/some_abc', function (req, res) {
        tempRoutes[req.body.uid+ '_P'] = function (request, response) {
            // handle the request and response
        };
        res.end();
    });
```

3. Using (and deleting) temporary route:

```
   app.post('/*_P', function(req, res) { // this will match any route ending with "_P"
       var path = req.path.substring(1); // get the temporary route name from the req object
       if(tempRoutes[path]) { // check if temporary route exists
           var routeFunction = tempRoutes[path];
           delete tempRoutes[path] // delete the temporary path
           routeFunction.apply(this, [req, res]); // apply the temporary route function
       } else {
           // handle 404
       }
   });
```

---

**NOTE:**

1. Tested, it worked for me.
2. It can be easily extended to include different route verbs.

Comment: I am not much experienced in node, i wanted to know is `tempRoutes[req.body.uid+ '_P'] = function (request, response) {
            // handle the request and response
        };`
this part is similar to

    `app.post('/' +req.body.uid+ '_P', function (reqa, resa) {
        // handle the request and response
    }); `
Will that `tempRoutes` will also listen on the post request?

Comment: No, `tempRoutes` is just an object containing the route functions. `app.post('/*_P', function(req, res) {  ... });` is actually listening to the post request and selecting which temporary route (from `tempRoutes`) to forward the post request to.

Comment: It is note adding, giving back `Cannot POST /UIDxyz_P`

Comment: I just tested it and it is working successfully without any further change to my code. Check if you've made any error.

Comment: with which version of nodejs you tested?

Comment: `tempRoutes` gives back a empty array! I am not getting how app.post() is taking from `tempRoutes`

Comment: My Node version is 4.2.3 and `tempRoutes` needs to be an object, not an array.

Comment: sorry, wrong word used, i defined as you wrote. `var tempRoutes = {};` have you tested it with opening that in browser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110959/discussion-between-blaze-sahlzen-and-samrat-das).