# ExpressJS : Modify route in a middleware

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Running an express app which for example has a route like `/home` and others. Now I want to change `url` to `/en/home`, `/sp/home` etc.

My requirement is to map these routes from `/en/home` to `/home` and similarly `/sp/home` to `/home` and add a header on request object on basis of `/en` and `/sp`

I want to write a middleware which will modify routes and extract information from it on basis of route as mentioned above.

I can use regex to do the second part but could not find a way to modify route on the fly.

Comment: Would this work or you have more requirements? `router.get('/:lang/home')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove route mappings in NodeJS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378690/remove-route-mappings-in-nodejs-express)

Comment: @Arpit, I dont want to change my existing routes in express as there are hundreds. I just want to extract the relevant information and then modify route to one of the existing route. Just want to minimize code change.

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378690/remove-route-mappings-in-nodejs-express/28369539#28369539

Answer (score -2):

You can try below middleware:

```
app.use('/en/home', function(req, res, next) {
    req.headers.lang = 'en';    
    res.redirect('/home');
});

app.use('/sp/home', function(req, res, next) {
    req.headers.lang = 'sp';    
    res.redirect('/home');
});
```

Comment: @ArpitSolanki updated the answer to store information in header in each middleware and then redirect it to home

Comment: Not a scalable solution. Just imagine you have hundreds of routes and lost of prefixes like /en/... , /sp/..., /hi/..., /ta/... etc